# Two network Macs have slow internet

Tags: performance, networking, ethernet, mac

I work in a boutique advertising agency as a web developer. I have my own servers at home for my website.

In our office, we have 8 Macs. Two of the iMacs are against one wall with an ethernet cable providing their connections to a wall outlet.

The internet on those two computers is super slow but still works. Pulling files off the network's server is usually OK, but sometimes causes the computer to freeze up.

Are there any commands I can run to do testing or fixes?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the cable ok?
2. Is the network configuration right?
3. Name resolution (DNS) works?

There are probably 1000 more such questions and possibilities. Could you provide more information?